# Energy in central force orbit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, energy, orbital-motion

Given a mass $m$ moving under the central force $$F(r) = -k/r^n$$

and a circular orbit passing through the force center, I want to show $n$ must equal 5. I ultimately arrive at the expression

$$E = \frac{l^2}{8R^2m\cos^4(\theta)} - \frac{k}{(n-1)(2R)^{n-1}\cos^{n-1}(\theta)}.$$

Now, I know for a circular orbit, energy must be independent of theta, so this is only fulfilled if $n=5$. However, I was told that $E$ would be zero for the motion? I don't believe this is true since $E=0$ for a parabolic orbit. Is my reasoning correct for why $n=5$? A little elaboration on the physics here would be very helpful.

Comment: Please define your symbols. How did you arrive at that expression?

Comment: Where is the center of the orbit?

Answer (score 0):

HINT:  In the case $n = 5$, your expression can be rewritten as
$$
E = \left( \frac{l^2}{8 R^2 m} - \frac{k}{4 (2R)^4} \right) \frac{1}{\cos^4 \theta}.
$$
Under what circumstances will this quantity be constant with respect to $\theta$?

[As an aside:  note that $E$ is a constant for *all* orbits, not just the circular ones as your question implies.]

Comment: I believe this is only a constant with respect to theta if E=0 ($l^2=\frac{km}{8R^2}$), but wouldn't that imply a parabolic orbit?

Comment: Does a $1/r^5$ force even have parabolic orbits? Parabolic orbits with $E=0$ are a feature of $1/r^2$ forces, but I don’t know that this is true for other inverse power laws.

Comment: @theta:  No, an $E = 0$ orbit is only parabolic for the $1/r^2$ force law.  Depending on the form of the potential, $E = 0$ orbits can be bounded, unbounded, or even nonexistent.